# How to leave the open file in eclipse tab after search?

Tags: tabs, eclipse

when we open a file from "Package Explorer" in eclipse, after we use it, it will leave in the tabs.

If we open a file from "Search" result, then after we search another keyword, it will disappear, we need to see the search result to find out that.

Is there any solution that I can leave the opened tab in the tabs after I opened from Search panel ?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

From main window, select Window - Preferences. On left, tree view, select General - Search. On the right, remove "Reuse editors to show matches". Click on OK button.

Comment: This is the most annoying Eclipse feature ever! Thanks.

Comment: Anti-feature.  Impediment.

Comment: yet another extremely annoying thing about eclipse and its standard settings .... i do hope some (actual) competition for it will exist at some point in the future - thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yet another annoying default setting, after fixing code highlight background hiding the code! Undiscoverable settings with random names scattered in the menus all over.

Comment: 8 years after this answer was posted, still need to manually change this setting in Eclipse

Comment: I arrive at this answer probably 6-10 times per year.  If I could, I would upvote this answer every time.  This Eclipse "feature" is so annoying.

Comment: @Woodchuck 13 years and still need to change it :(

Comment: Absolutely astounding.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse Kepler, if you double click on the found file (NOT THE FOUND TEXT) in the search, it will replace the file you double click to open previously. So to keep both files open, right click on the another found file in the search window and select open, this will retain the file you open previously.

Comment: I like this solution better than the accepted answer, because it let's you choose on a match-by-match basis.